# Typo3 8.7.x / Extbase / Typoscript: How to set the storagePid for adding new custom object to tt_content (mm relation)

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-8.x

I extended my tt_content table to add new custom objects to it with a mm relation. That is working fine, but I don't want to add the new custom object at the same page. I tried the following typoscript, but it's not working, any ideas?

```
module.tx_myext {
    persistence {
        classes {
            MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Iconlink {
                newRecordStoragePid = 45
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code

```
plugin.tx_myext {
  persistence {
    classes {
        MyVendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Iconlink {
            newRecordStoragePid = 45
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: plugin is only for frontent, but I need it for the backend